# Why does priming a http client improve performance after JVM snapshot restore when all classes where loaded and initialized?

Tags: java, jvm

During performance testing after restoring JVM snapshots, I observed a notable improvement in performance for the initial [HttpClient::send](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html#send(java.net.http.HttpRequest,java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandler)) call when performing a [HttpClient::send](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html#send(java.net.http.HttpRequest,java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandler)) even to an arbitrary domain before taking the JVM snapshot. This improvement was also evident when all related classes were preloaded and initialized before taking the snapshot using `Class.forName(.., true, ..)` (I collected all involved classes from the JVM logs).

Although the first call post-restore isn't as quick as subsequent ones (due to factors like connection reuse), it's still faster than expected, considering all classes are already loaded. I'm exploring the reasons for this speed increase:

1. Connection Reuse: Unlikely, as connections aren't preserved post-snapshot restore.
2. Thread Reuse: Similarly improbable for the same reason.
3. DNS Caching: Unlikely, since a different top-level domain was used and the performance gain exceeded typical DNS caching benefits.
4. Caching: This could be a factor for certain internal processes not initialized as static or those evaluated lazily.
5. JIT Compiling: A possibility, AWS Lambda runs with `-XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1`.

Could JIT compiling be the primary reason for this observed performance increase?

Comment: Almost certainly.  It is perfectly normal for JVM code to speed up tremendously after the JIT has an opportunity to work.

Comment: @LouisWasserman But is JIT kicking in that early? My understanding was that it first starts in bytecode interpreter mode and only way later kicks in with level 1 and 2 optimizations, probably after a lot of method calls. But maybe they are called that often already by a simple single call.

Comment: How do you snapshot-restore the JVM? Have you tried profiling?

Answer (score 0):

JIT Compiling: This is a very likely contributor to the performance increase you're observing. The Just-In-Time (JIT) compiler in the JVM optimizes code at runtime based on its actual usage patterns. The -XX:+TieredCompilation and -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 flags indicate that the JVM is using a tiered compilation approach, which starts with quicker, less optimized compilation and can optimize further as needed.

When you perform an HttpClient::send before taking the snapshot, the JIT compiler may optimize parts of the HttpClient code based on this usage. These optimizations are then preserved in the snapshot. Upon restoration, even though the JIT compiler may have more work to do for further optimization (hence the first call post-restore not being as quick as subsequent ones), the restored JVM starts with a version of the HttpClient code that's already been through some level of JIT compilation optimization.